# Uft dropdown getting deselected to default value

Tags: hp-uft

I have clicked on dropdown button. Passed the value as innertext to we web elements in dropdown n selected it. After selecting its going back to default value    I have tried sync. Wait time. Replay types. Fit events but same issue. Pls help

Select weblist value and remain same